# Retrieving url from feedparser media:content

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

The following code works fine:

```
if 'media_content' in entry:
                mediaContent=entry.media_content
            else:
                mediaContent='No Media'
```

But this gives me an error:

```
 if 'media_content' in entry:
                mediaContent=entry.media_content['url']
            else:
                mediaContent='No Media'
```

This is the error:

```
list indices must be integers, not str
```

I've seen multiple uses of this syntax when searching on the web to pull out the url from the media_content element of feedparser, but it isn't working for me. I'm new to python, so I'm sure it is just that I'm not accessing the dictionary properly. I just want the raw url as a string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`entry.media_content` is a *list* of entries, each a dictionary:

```
for item in entry.media_content:
    print item['url']
```

You could just grab the first one listed:

```
if 'media_content' in entry:
    mediaContent = entry.media_content[0]['url']
```